# Vapor Build Getting Failed

Tags: api, vapor, swift4.1

Iam Currently New to Vapor Swift Server side initially i have Two Queries

> 1) **Problem**

Vapor build is getting Failed

> Error:

Build failed.

> 2)  Question

While Running i getting localhost:8080/Hello this url works fine in Safari browser

When comes to Ios Application I Calling that URl GET Method i getting

> Error

error getting http:0.0.0.0:8080/Hello, HTTP status code 503

how to Test the Vapor Api's Outside of Any languages like Java,Javascript etc

Comment: Include Vapor's version (use `vapor --version`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind Vapor to `0.0.0.0` (`127.0.0.1` might also work in your network) instead of `localhost` (default):

```swift
public func configure(
    _ config: inout Config,
    _ env: inout Environment,
    _ services: inout Services
) throws {

    services.register(EngineServerConfig.default(hostname: "0.0.0.0"))
    ...
}
```

If you are deploying to heroku/etc, you can set it in your Procfile instead:

```sh
web: Run serve -e production -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```